# Questions to find the indirect object

Tags: word-choice, prepositional-phrases, indirect-objects

"The indirect object answers the question “To whom?” or “For whom?” the action of the verb is performed."
For example:

1. He gives María the book.
   **To whom does he give the book?**
   To María.
   IO = María
2. He buys me flowers.
   **For whom does he buy the flowers?**
   For me.
   IO = me

I would like to know why in sentence number 1 we ask to whom and not for whom, and why in sentence number 2 we ask for whom and not to whom. In other words, how do I know when to ask to whom and when to ask for whom in order to find the indirect object.

Comment: Most native speakers today (particularly in normal conversation) wouldn't use ***whom*** at all in these examples. And they'd put the preposition at the end: ***Who** did he give the book **to**?*

Comment: For purposes of finding the indirect object, it's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

We *give* something **to** someone. *To* whom did he give the book?

We *buy a gift* **for** someone.  *For* whom did he buy the flowers?

Who are those flowers **for**?
--They're for my girlfriend.